# Thunderbird keep retrieving all Yahoo emails from the pop server

Tags: thunderbird, pop3, yahoo-mail

Thunderbird suddenly retrieves all my 2000+ emails from the Yahoo pop server every time I check my mail. My account setting is to have the mails stored on the server until I delete them.

Comment: You should mark the answer below as "Answered" with the check mark if it solves your problem...

Answer (score 0):

You may need to delete the `popstate.dat` and let Thunderbird recreate it (that's the file that keeps track of which messages have been downloaded).  See [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Repeatably_downloading_the_same_messages) for details.  It will have to download all the messages one more time, and then it should be able to keep track.

Comment: Following the steps given, the problem is solved. Thanks.